# Learning how to use WFS Filter?

Tags: wfs, ogc, references

I need to learn about the WFS Filter.

is their any website or book where we can learn about WFS and its filter by example.

i have seen the OGC website where we have only xsd.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://www.ogcnetwork.net/wfstutorial ?

Comment: Tutorial seems to show only BBOX example but nothing about true filters. Filter encoding standard you must read anyway but making working filters by reading it may prove difficult. Have a try still.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you install [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/) somewhere and start playing.

There is a number of examples in the [GeoServer documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html).

Comment: i have read geoserver document. but its very limited. i need to know about the Filter based on geometry.

Comment: how about http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/filter_reference.html

Comment: There are also some samples in the Demo request application of the GeoServer admin utility. You must be logged in for using that.